# How Do I tie 2 ports of I have a dell 5448 togather for a teamed pair of broadcomm nic's

Tags: command-line-interface, switch

I have 3 dell 1950 servers that have 2 broadcomm gigabit nic's in them. The Broadcomm software made teaming the pair quite easy. How Do I configure a dell  5448 switch for 3 2GB paths on six ports for the 3 servers.

My heyday was with NT4, long before Dell was around.

Answer (score 1):

For the most part, you're done already if the ports are on the same VLAN.

Now... that being said, from the SERVER perspective Broadcom's smart load balancing is going to provide you 2Gb of transmit (it will round robin transmits), but the switch is only going to respond on one of the links providing you 1Gb.

In order to get bi-directional 2Gb load balancing, you'll need to configure the switch to use link aggregation, and change the server to use 802.3ad link aggregation. You can also enhance that link with a protocol called LACP which verifies both links are functioning.

To set a port on a Dell switch to be part of an aggregate link, you would use a command like: channel-group 1 mode on. This creates an STATIC aggregate link called port-channel 1 which you would then configure like any other switchport. Be sure to set the second port similarly.

If you wish to enhance this LAG with LACP protocol instead, you would use the command on the interface instead: channel-group 1 mode auto (or mode active to force it, I suggest auto).

There are a few other things to keep in mind here:

1) If you make a configuration like this on the switch, you need match your "teaming" selection on the server

2) If your switches are not "stacked" to act as one unit, both links must go to the same switch. If you have more than one switch and just have a simple link between the two and are not "stacking" then you cannot build an aggregate across those two switches.

Plenty of examples out there:

http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/networking/f/4454/t/19449466.aspx

However, on the whole, I recommend you just put both ports on the same VLAN and call it a day unless you hit some kind of performance bottleneck.